# WordPress - make default search function return color and colour when searching for color

Tags: wordpress

I am looking to modify the current default search function so when searching color or colour it will return all post types containing ether one.
I have looked at "pre_get_posts" but it doesn't give me any methods to search with multiple values. I would like to avoid writing a custom query if the is a WordPress way.

```
This is my current code



add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'color_search' );
function color_search( $query ) {
  $search_items = [
   'colour' => ['color', 'colour'],
   'color' => ['color', 'colour']
  ];
  if ( $query->query_vars['s'] ) {
    foreach($search_items as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . ' ' .$query->query['s'] . "\n";
      if ( $query->query_vars['s'] === $key ) {
        $query->set('s', $value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```